# How to copy jenkins users to another server

Tags: jenkins

i want to copy my existing windows jenkins users to linux jenkins server. How to do that?

i have copied users directory to my current server after restarted the service still not working.

Comment: What do you mean "still not working"? Can they log in (authenticate)? Do they have access? Do you have similar authentication and access control? Can you (admin) log in?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that's happening because Jenkins encrypts passwords, so a new instance would not work unless you had the same key as before in the new instance.

So on top of copying over the users directory, you'll want to copy over the secrets directory as well as the secret.key file, which can all be found in your $JENKINS_HOME directory:

- $JENKINS_HOME/secret.key
- $JENKINS_HOME/secrets
- $JENKINS-HOME/users

Copying over all of those should address your issue